# Completed job run times linux

Tags: linux, bash, runtime

I am running a series of very long jobs. So far one has completed but I forgot to check how long it was running for before it finished.
Is there a way to find out how long a completed process took in linux?

Comment: for the ones that are still running, `ps -ef | grep myProgram` will show you the starting time as part of the output. In the future, run your jobs like `time myProgram args .... &` . Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For processes that are still running, this is possible as follows:

Check the time that `/proc/process-PID` was created: `stat /proc/myprocesspid`

For processes that are complete, unless that process creates logs, then this is not possible.

To find out the process PID you can use the `top` command which will allow you to see an interactive ordered list of busy processes, or `ps -aux` which will show you all processes on the system as a long list.

Answer (score 0):

If you job didn't output some dedicated log you might want to look at `/var/log/messages` or `dmesg` (or wherever system log messages are stored depending on you distribution). With a little bit of luck you find some output that might help you.